# JavaScript - Factorialization 'For Loop' Understanding?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am in the midst of completing some JavaScript algorithmic challenges and I had to factorialize a number as part of one of them. After searching through stack and other places I entered a correct code block:

```
function factorialize(num) {

    if(num === 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    if(num < 0 ) {
        return undefined;
    }

    for(var i = num; --i; ) {
        num *= i;
    }
        return num;
}

factorialize(5);
```

It it returns a correct result. What I am struggling to understand however is why the for loop doesn't have a second statement, and why it can run for ever? I have an inkling it's because as soon as `i` value is `0`, any subsequent negative number that is generated will be multiplied by 0 and so only the integer numbers will form the result. But why does the function return a valid number, if the loop is still running to -infinity and hasn't been told to stop when reaching a certain value?

Comment: it doesn't have a third statement ... and that's valid enough ... the second statement breaks the loop when i is 1 (i.e. --i will be 0) ... for loop is defined as `for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression])` ... condition is what tests to see if the loop should keep running, as long as it evaluates truthy, loop continues. Initialization is run ONCE before the first loop, finalization is run at the end of every loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All elements in a for-loop's expression are optional.

The second part of the for-loop is used to express the for-loop's *condition*. The condition is evaluated on every iteration, and when it evaluates to false, the loop is exited.

In this case, that second part that expresses the condition is `--i`. This means that on every iteration, `i` will be decremented by 1, until it finally reaches zero (0). Since 0 is considered to be a *falsey* value in Javascript, the loop exits.

Comment: Thanks Robby, that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

the second part of your `for` loop is the Condition:

> An expression to be evaluated before each loop iteration. If this expression evaluates to true, statement is executed. This conditional test is optional. If omitted, the condition always evaluates to true. If the expression evaluates to false, execution skips to the first expression following the for construct.

Once `--i` reaches 0, it evaluates to `false` (*falsey*) and the `for` "exits"

adding a `console.log(i)` to your for loop will help demonstrate that

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: Thanks Luca, that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

`for (a; b; c)`

is a direct equivalent to

```
a;
while (b) {
    c;
}
```

You're mistaken here because you seem to think that `c` is what determines the end of the loop, but `b` actually is. You can omit the third loop statement if you don't need it (as well as the first one).

Here, your loop is equivalent to:

```
var i = num;
while (--i) {
    num *= i;
}
```

`while (--i)` does two things:

- Decrement `i` (before anything else)
- Check that `i != 0` (this is the actual loop condition).

If it was `i--`, note that the operations would be done in the opposite order.

If you find the code hard to read, you can also write it this way for the same results:

```
for (var i = num - 1; i != 0; i--) {
    num *= i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would have :

```
for(var i = 0; i < num; i++)
```

the second statement is a boolean continuation expression. 
So when you have

```
for(var i = num; i--;)
```

The second is still a boolean continuation expression and when i get to 0 it evaluated to false.